# How to compute the number of equivalence classes under the relation $a\sim b\iff a=x^m b x^n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algorithms, equivalence-relations, computational-algebra

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Fix an element $x\in G$, and denote by $\sim$ the equivalence relation on $G$ given by $a\sim b \iff \exists m,n\text{ such that }a=x^m b x^n$.

Example: Let $G=\langle(123),(567),(1234)(5678)\rangle\leq S_8$ and choose $x=(1234)(5678)$. We have $\left|G\right|=288$. There are 16 classes containing 16 elements, 2 classes containing 8 elements, and 4 classes containing 4 elements for a total of $\left|G/\sim\right|=22$ classes.

> Is there an efficient algorithm or formula to compute this for an arbitrary group $G$? What about if a representative of each class is required as well?

The "brute-force" way to compute it would be to loop through the elements of $G$ and number each element based on the class it appears in, but this requires $O(\left|G\right|)$ memory so it is inefficient if $G$ is large.

Comment: [Related.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) (No pun intended.)

Comment: (I'm thinking of Green's $\mathcal{J}$ relation.)

Comment: (Not for the pun . . . )